# DateTime.Now in Model C# ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created a model for Articles, and in the articles I am trying to implement a date created on initial create.

//Model

```
    [Display(Name = "Date Created")]
    public DateTime dateCreated
    {
        get { return DateTime.Now; }
    }
```

It works well when I create an article, but it also sets the same date time value to all the other articles. :/

Is there a way around this?

cheers.

Comment: I think model properties need to be read/write.  How else would they be able to deserialize back from the client?

Answer (score 5):

Putting that in a property will evaluate the `DateTime.Now` each time the property is accessed, so if you query it twice, you'll get two different values.

There are a number of possible options for modeling this, but normally you'll want a read-only property set-ed in the constructor:

```
public Article()
{
    This.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
}

[Display(Name = "Date Created")]
public DateTime DateCreated {get; private set;}
```

Comment: This is a wrong approach..What if the Save will occur after a minute? it would not reflect the real time of the creation.

Comment: @YairNevet It really depends on how you interpret "Created". Is it when you instantiate the object? Is it when you execute some "save" function? Is it when it finally reaches the data store? Given that the OP hasn't been that detailed, and for most approaches the save occurs instants after creating the object, I think this approach is fine. Otherwise, put a `TRIGGER` or `DEFAULT` constraint on the DB.

Comment: Most the times you would want to see when the object was created in the database, otherwise this object is just a memory object.

Answer (score 2):

> It works well when I create an article, but it also sets the same date
>   time value to all the other articles.

This is exactly why it is a bad idea. Get what you do is exposing the current date and time with that property.

Why can't you set it right before you save your changes?

For instance:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
  DateTime saveTime = DateTime.Now;
  foreach (var entry in this.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e => e.State == System.Data.EntityState.Added))
   {
     if (entry.Property("dateCreated").CurrentValue == null)
       entry.Property("dateCreated").CurrentValue = saveTime;
    }
    return base.SaveChanges();

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's what you need:

```
private DateTime? dateCreated;
public DateTime DateCreated
{
    get { return dateCreated ?? DateTime.Now; }
    set { dateCreated = value; }
}
```

What this does is wait until this property is first accessed. Then, it will see if a created date has already been set and if not, it will set it to `DateTime.Now`. For initial creates, this will usually happen when EF attempts to save it to the database, which is exactly when you want that to happen. It would only happen sooner if you tried to manually access the property before saving, but there's no good reason why you would do that. The set method just allows a normal set, so when EF pulls this from the database, it will just set the private field and it will always be set to that.

Comment: This should work, but somehow when I edit a model entity the dateCreated field becomes null and then gets set to DateTime.Now again.

Comment: You need to make sure you're not posting a value for it implicitly. If you're just using the entity directly with your form, but don't include at least a hidden field for the `DateCreated` property, then it will be set as null. You'll need to either include a hidden field (not ideal), manually map the value from the entity pulled fresh from the database after post, or use a view model to do the same. The key is that you need to make sure the original value is there before you update your entity.

Comment: I get it now. The form is posting the null value for it. I edited the controller to pull the date from the database before persisting the changes. I wonder how a viewModel fits in the MVC picture here.